# Moisture sensor error with node-RED and Raspi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, sensors, node-red, grovepi+

I'm starting with grove sensor and node-RED with my Raspi 3.

I already installed node-RED server. I can connect actually :

- DHT11 (temp and humidity)
- Ds18b20 (temp)
- Relay
- remote to my phone

My problem is about moisture sensor, when I use "grove capacitive moisture sensor" node, my server crash and I can see an error on log :

```
error: command failed : python -u /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor/grove-capacity-moisture-sensor.py 4
 at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:400:12)
 at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
 at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
 code: 2,
 killed: false,
 signal: null,
 cmd: 'python -u /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor/grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor.py 4'
```

Sensor is connected to A4 like an analog sensor. I don't understand why doesn't work.
I use timestamp on input like other sensor.

My setup :

Raspi 3
grove base hat

Thanks for your return and your help.

Regards.

edit :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor $ python -u grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor.py 4 

pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor $
```

Comment: What happens if you run `python -u /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor/grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor.py 4` on the command line?

Comment: And with the `4`? Since that is what is actually run by the node. I want the FULL output

Comment: I tested with and without : same result.

I haven't output on debug node. I changed analog input on node A4 to A0 and on syslog,  I can see 0 after python script error.

Comment: they talk about "trigger" for input. Do you know why , and which setup need on trigger node ?

Comment: No, this test is outside of node-red, I want you to open a terminal and run the command and then edit the question to show the output in the terminal. It won't show anything from the debug node

Comment: Sorry, I tested on terminal too. I haven't return on terminal.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73720282/edit) the question when adding detail. That way it can be formatted to be readable

Comment: OK, assuming that the sensor is working and you have the right port number (`4`) that command should return the current value from the sensor. The Node will run that command every time it receives an input message. Since it's not working and not giving any reason why, I suggest you open an issue with the maintainer here: https://gitlab.com/mediaessenz/node-red-contrib-grove-capacitive-moisture-sensor/-/issues

Comment: I added a new issue on gitlab. Thanks for your help.